# Does my neural network have a normal distributed output?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, conv-neural-network

I have trained a binary classier neural network and I was interested in potentially using some standard statical analysis on it although they are often reliant on if the underlying distribution is normal.

I have no idea if my neural network produces a normally distributed output, is there anyway to test such a thing?

would it be correct to just take small portions of the data (say 10 images at a time) and calculate the response to check normality?

Comment: No, but why would you care at all?

Comment: I care because many statistical methods assume a normal distribution

Comment: What “statistical method” do you want to use with neural network?

Comment: For example, I could calculate the confidence interval of the classification accuracy for a data set.

Comment: No you can’t. Methods like linear regression are designed in such way that it is easy to calculate things like confidence intervals given that a set of assumptions holds. Neither of this applies to machine learning.

Comment: You can use bootstrap for confidence intervals if your dataset is small enough that you can in reasonable time retrain your network several thousand times.

Comment: The distribution of the output ultimately depends on the distribution of the input, doesn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your neural network is a binary classifier, then it's likely true that the last layer is a sigmoid unit which outputs a number between 0 and 1. Since the normal distribution isn't bounded between 0 and 1, the output can't be normally distributed.

Comment: Its softmax but yeah good point thanks

Comment: Actually maybe for my own understanding is this because a normal distribution is normally unbound but our NN is bound?

Comment: yes, that's the reasoning